# How to use custom logger for vs test?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

I'm trying to use this custom Teamcity logger  for VsTest per https://github.com/JakeGinnivan/VSTest.TeamCityLogger and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj155796.aspx

After copying the `vstest.teamcity.logger.dll` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\Extensions` I have it working with the command

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" Tests.dll /logger:vstest.teamcity.logger.dll/TeamCityLogger
```

However other users don't have `vstest.teamcity.logger.dll/` installed at that location. They do have it in the working directory though. How can I run vstest specifying the precise path?

Answer (score -1):

As an option, you can provide users with a convenient script to copy the dll into Visual Studio folder before the test run.